# Can I throw multiple json from a single page?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I want to throw multiple json from this page so that I an fetch json file to show the output for my mobile application with java programming. Following is my code which displays proper json from table "news" however, I want to throw json of other object available in my database. Is that possible?

```
    $dblink = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

    mysqli_query($dblink, 'SET NAMES utf8');

    //Check connection was successful
      if ($dblink->connect_errno) {
         printf("Failed to connect to database");
         exit();
      } 

      $result = $dblink->query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC");


      $dbdata = array();

      while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
        $dbdata[]=$row;
      }

     echo json_encode($dbdata);

    ?>
```

Comment: combine into an another array and send it as json .

Comment: Yes you can send, Merge into array and using json_encode you can send.

Comment: What do you mean by `throw`? Assuming you don't mean [throwing an exception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#In_software)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's up to you how you combine them, it could be as simple as:

**Merge:**

```
$dbdata = array_merge($dbdata1, $dbdata2);
echo json_encode(dbdata);
```

**Different Keys:**

```
$dbdata = array(
'table_1' => $dbdata1,
'table_2' => $dbdata2
);
echo json_encode($dbdata);
```

**MySQL Join:**

```
SELECT n.*, m.* FROM news n LEFT JOIN news_meta m ON m.news_id = n.news_id ORDER BY n.id DESC;

/* $dbdata will then contain your two tables worth of data: */
echo json_encode($dbdata);
```

Comment: Yes, it gives the array of both table but how will I know which array is from table_1 and which array is from table_2.

Comment: If you want your JSON to clearly show which table it is from, that my answer shows you the "different keys" method.